# when click "edit" button ,appear" Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."exception

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I think i checked the " if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)" but still cannot work " edit "is cells[3]   "delete" is cells[4],  when I click edit button,
it will give me

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Source Error:

Line 252:                    LinkButton lkDelete = (LinkButton)gv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0];

really dont know where is wrong....

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        LinkButton lkDelete = (LinkButton)gv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0];
                        lkDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm(' Are you sure you want to delete this item?');";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looping through each row every time a row binds.  Either remove the loop:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    LinkButton lkDelete = (LinkButton)gv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0];
    lkDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm(' Are you sure you want to delete this item?');";
}
```

or add the delete confirmation in the GUI instead of in the code-behind:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this item?');" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
 LinkButton lkDelete = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
                      
 lkDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm(' Are you sure you want to delete this item?');";
 }like this? still can not find that control ,exception again

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the proper cell/control?  Instead of (LinkButton)gv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0];  try using FindControl instead: (LinkButton)gv.FindControl("buttonname");

Comment: yes only "delete" in that cell , when i add   if (e.Row.Cells[4].HasControls()), it works

Comment: @Xu Kun : Without seeing your Grid code, it's difficult to say what's failing.  Have you tried using the .FindControl method?  Alternatively, using my 2nd suggestion (OnClientClick) will allow you to skip finding the control at all...

Answer (score 0):

First, the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event is raised when every single data row is bound to data in the GridView control. So you do not need to looping through the grid as you are doing right now.

Second, your code seems find unless the index is out of range, which is probably at controls[0].
My suggestion is to use FindControl insteads:

```
  protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        LinkButton lkDelete = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("lkDeleteId");
        lkDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm(' Are you sure you want to delete this item?');";
     }
  }
```

EDIT:

You still need to check for [RowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx)  before perform an operation you are doing, because you dont want to do this in Header, Footer or Pager row.

Comment: thanks !I remove the for loop,and I found if i remove                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)   and add                    if (e.Row.Cells[4].HasControls())  it can work  ,so  is e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow  necessary here?